# Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type bool and string

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to change the number of items within a variable when they are purchased in-app.

In the UICollectionView, I want to have a condition where if the stringforkey from UserDefaults is equal to two strings, then the following code will be used.

Here it is

```
else if userDefault.stringForKey("purchases") == "unlockthemecoll2" && "unlockthemecoll1"
```

Why can't I do this, I get the error written in the title of this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userDefault.stringForKey("purchases")` can't have two values at the same time.

If you want to check whether it has one of the values or the other, you should do that :

```
else if userDefault.stringForKey("purchases") == "unlockthemecoll2" || userDefault.stringForKey("purchases") == "unlockthemecoll1"
```